# Extra page is generated on print when HTML invoice with Header and Footer repeated on each page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to generate `HTML` invoice with `header` at `top` and `footer` at `bottom` repeated on each page with content in middle. After making some hacks I was able to achieve it. But extra page is getting generated at the end. The first two page has content but third page is extra and empty.

Here is the code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        @media print {
            table {
                width: 100%;
            }

            table.report-container {
                page-break-after: always;
            }

            thead.report-header {
                display: table-header-group;
            }

            tfoot.report-footer {
                display: table-footer-group;
            }

            td.report-footer-cell {
                height: 8rem;
            }

            table.report-container div.main {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
            }

            body {
                font-family: Calibri, monospace;
                font-size: 0.8rem;
                margin: 1rem;
                /* border: 1px solid; */
            }

            ol {
                list-style: none;
                padding-left: 0;
                margin: 0.5rem 0;
            }

            header {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                padding: 0 0.5rem;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                position: relative;
            }

            #invoicedetails {
                display: grid;
                grid: "shop customer invoice";
                grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
                padding: 0 0.5rem;
            }

            #customer {
                border: 1px solid;
                border-top: 0;
                border-bottom: 0;
                padding-left: 0.5rem;
            }

            #invoice {
                text-align: right;
            }

            #invoiceitems {
                display: grid;
                border: 1px solid;
                border-left: 0;
                border-right: 0;
                border-top: 0;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            #itemscontent {
                display: grid;
                grid: "sno description price unit unitprice";
                grid-auto-rows: minmax(1rem, max-content);
                grid-column-gap: 1px;
                border: 1px solid;
                border-left: 0;
                border-right: 0;
                align-items: center;
            }

            #itemscontent>div {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                border: 1px solid;
                height: 100%;
                border-top: 0;
                border-right: 0;
                padding: 0 0.25rem;
            }

            .span-3 {
                grid-column-start: span 3;
            }

            #itemsfooter {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            #itemsfooter>div {
                align-self: stretch;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                padding: 0 0.5rem;
            }

            #amountinwords {
                flex: 75%;
            }

            #totalamount {
                flex: 25%;
                text-align: right;
                border-left: 1px solid black;
            }

            #totalamount ol {
                width: 100%;
            }

            #totalamount ol li:last-child {
                font-size: x-large;
            }

            #invoiceinformation {
                grid-area: invoiceinformation;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: end;
                padding: 0 0.5rem;
            }

            #signature {
                padding-left: 0.5rem;
            }

            #footer {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 15;
                width: 97%;
            }

            @page {
                size: A4;

                @top-right {
                    content: counter(page);
                    z-index: 9999;
                }
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="report-container">
        <thead class="report-header">
            <tr>
                <th class="report-header-cell">
                    <div class="header-info">
                        <header>
                            
                        </header>
                        <section id="invoicedetails">
                            <section id="shop">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>From</li>

                                    <li><b>Book Publications</b></li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>

                            <section id="customer">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>To</li>

                                    <li><b>Abdul Rahman </b></li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>

                            <section id="invoice">
                                <ol>

                                    <li>Invoice Details</li>
                                    <li>Invoice No: <b>2/2023-24</b></li>

                                    <li>Invoice Date: <b>02 Oct 2023</b></li>

                                    <li>Payment Mode: <b>Cash</b></li>

                                    <li>Payment Status: Paid</li>

                                    <li>Invoice Amount: <b>₹70.00</b></li>
                                </ol>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot class="report-footer">
            <tr>
                <td class="report-footer-cell">
                    <div class="footer-info">
                        <!-- <section id="itemsfooter">
                            <div id="amountinwords">
                                <ol>
                                    <li><small>Total Amount in Words (INR)</small></li>

                                    <li><b>seventy ONLY</b></li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>

                            <div id="totalamount">
                                <ol>

                                    <li><small>Total Amount</small></li>
                                    <li><b>₹70.00</b></li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                        <section id="invoiceinformation">
                            <div id="signature">
                                <text>
                                    for Book Publications<br><br><br>Authorized Signatory
                                </text>
                            </div>
                        </section> -->
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody class="report-content">
            <tr>
                <td class="report-content-cell">
                    <div class="main">
                        <section id="invoiceitems">
                            <section id="itemscontent"
                                style="grid-template-rows: repeat(43, minmax(1rem, max-content)) auto repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content)); grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, auto) max-content max-content max-content">

                                <div class="border-left-0">S.No</div>
                                <div>Description</div>
                                <div>Price</div>
                                <div>Unit</div>
                                <div>Unit Price</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
                                <div>Novel - Akka</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

                                <div class="border-left-0"></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>

                                <div class="border-left-0 flex-end span-3">Sub Total</div>
                                <div class="flex-end">1</div>

                                <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
                                <div class="border-left-0 flex-end span-3">Discount </div>

                                <div></div>
                                <div class="flex-end">-₹30.00</div>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="footer">
        <section id="itemsfooter">
            <div id="amountinwords">
                <ol>
                    <li><small>Total Amount in Words (INR)</small></li>

                    <li><b>seventy ONLY</b></li>
                </ol>
            </div>

            <div id="totalamount">
                <ol>

                    <li><small>Total Amount</small></li>
                    <li><b>₹70.00</b></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="invoiceinformation">
            <div id="signature">
                <text>
                    for Book Publications<br><br><br>Authorized Signatory
                </text>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please assist me on what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use position fixed for that.
All you need to do is add the footer inside the table foot and remove the position fixed that you had.

```css
@media print {
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  table.report-container {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
  thead.report-header {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  tfoot.report-footer {
    display: table-footer-group;
  }
  td.report-footer-cell {
    height: 8rem;
  }
  table.report-container div.main {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  body {
    font-family: Calibri, monospace;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    /* border: 1px solid; */
  }
  ol {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
  }
  #invoicedetails {
    display: grid;
    grid: "shop customer invoice";
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
  }
  #customer {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  }
  #invoice {
    text-align: right;
  }
  #invoiceitems {
    display: grid;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #itemscontent {
    display: grid;
    grid: "sno description price unit unitprice";
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(1rem, max-content);
    grid-column-gap: 1px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #itemscontent>div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
  }
  .span-3 {
    grid-column-start: span 3;
  }
  #itemsfooter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #itemsfooter>div {
    align-self: stretch;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
  }
  #amountinwords {
    flex: 75%;
  }
  #totalamount {
    flex: 25%;
    text-align: right;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
  }
  #totalamount ol {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #totalamount ol li:last-child {
    font-size: x-large;
  }
  #invoiceinformation {
    grid-area: invoiceinformation;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
  }
  #signature {
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  }
  #footer {
    width: 97%;
  }
  @page {
    size: A4;
    @top-right {
      content: counter(page);
      z-index: 9999;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="report-container">
  <thead class="report-header">
    <tr>
      <th class="report-header-cell">
        <div class="header-info">
          <header>

          </header>
          <section id="invoicedetails">
            <section id="shop">
              <ol>
                <li>From</li>

                <li><b>Book Publications</b></li>
              </ol>
            </section>

            <section id="customer">
              <ol>
                <li>To</li>

                <li><b>Abdul Rahman </b></li>
              </ol>
            </section>

            <section id="invoice">
              <ol>

                <li>Invoice Details</li>
                <li>Invoice No: <b>2/2023-24</b></li>

                <li>Invoice Date: <b>02 Oct 2023</b></li>

                <li>Payment Mode: <b>Cash</b></li>

                <li>Payment Status: Paid</li>

                <li>Invoice Amount: <b>₹70.00</b></li>
              </ol>
            </section>
          </section>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot class="report-footer">
    <tr>
      <td class="report-footer-cell">
        <div class="footer-info">
          <div id="footer">
            <section id="itemsfooter">
              <div id="amountinwords">
                <ol>
                  <li><small>Total Amount in Words (INR)</small></li>

                  <li><b>seventy ONLY</b></li>
                </ol>
              </div>

              <div id="totalamount">
                <ol>

                  <li><small>Total Amount</small></li>
                  <li><b>₹70.00</b></li>
                </ol>
              </div>
            </section>

            <section id="invoiceinformation">
              <div id="signature">
                <text>
                    for Book Publications<br><br><br>Authorized Signatory
                  </text>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody class="report-content">
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          <section id="invoiceitems">
            <section id="itemscontent" style="grid-template-rows: repeat(43, minmax(1rem, max-content)) auto repeat(2, minmax(1rem, max-content)); grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, auto) max-content max-content max-content">

              <div class="border-left-0">S.No</div>
              <div>Description</div>
              <div>Price</div>
              <div>Unit</div>
              <div>Unit Price</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0">1</div>
              <div>Novel - Akka</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>
              <div class="flex-end">₹70.00</div>

              <div class="border-left-0"></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>

              <div class="border-left-0 flex-end span-3">Sub Total</div>
              <div class="flex-end">1</div>

              <div class="flex-end">₹100.00</div>
              <div class="border-left-0 flex-end span-3">Discount </div>

              <div></div>
              <div class="flex-end">-₹30.00</div>
            </section>
          </section>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But this will print footer in all pages right? I need footer in only last page. That's why I have added position fixed hack